# how to pass a changing variable to another class useing .putExtra()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a `int` called **Money** to another class but it keeps telling me "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `putExtra(String, int)` from the type `Intent`"

```
int Money = 0;

GoToSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), settings.class);
                Intent.putExtra("Money",Money);
                //^^^^^that's the variable i am trying to use
                startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

"Money" constantly changes and I don't know how else to get it to go to my second class.

PS I am still trying to learn how to use this site so please bear with me if I didn't do something right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `Intent.putExtra("Money",Money);` to `intent.putExtra("Money",Money);`
`Intent` is a *class*, `intent` is an *instance* of `Intent`, and `putExtra()` is an instance level method so you have to call it using `intent`